# Redux persist migration empty migrationKeys

Tags: react-native, redux-persist

```
export const migrations = {
  0: (state: any) => {
    return {
      ...state,
      someObject: { ...state.someObject, someItem: true },
    };
  },
};
```

---

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
...
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  version: 3,
  migrate: createMigrate(migrations, { debug: true }),
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
...
```

[image]

Nothing is migrated!

Comment: What version of `redux-persist` are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The 0 in your migrations object is the version to which you will be migrating. So you need to match that with the version number inside your persistConfig.version

I recommend you change the 0 to 3 in your migrations object since downgrades are not supported.

Comment: Cheers, I'll give that a go.